# Test using an invalid JSON passed in test_request_context (Flask)

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, pytest

For testing purposes, is there a way to pass an invalid JSON in the `test_request_context`?

```py
# test_example.py
from app import app
from example import get_param  # the method I am interested in unit testing
import flask

bad_json = # some bad JSON

def test_get_param_aborts(app):
    with app.test_request_context('/', data=flask.json.dumps(bad_json), content_type='application/json'):
            # assert output based on a request with a bad json
```

Comment: What is your current output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dumps` is never going to produce an invalid JSON document (it would raise an exception instead thus spoiling your test) but there shouldn't be any problem creating an invalid JSON manually:

```py
# test_example.py
from app import app
from example import get_param

def test_get_param_aborts(app):
    with app.test_request_context('/', data='abc', content_type='application/json'):
        # assert output based on a request with a bad json
```

**Note**: `'abc'` is not a valid JSON while `'"abc"'` would be.

Comment: I see. Can you help me understand how I could pass a valid json as a string i.e. without the `json.dumps`? For example, this `{"a": "stra", "b": strb"}` is a valid json that the `json.dumps` handles OK.

Comment: JSON is a text format so for Python it **is a string**. Simply just pass `data='{"a": "stra", "b": strb"}'`. There really isn't any magic behind this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - was being silly there for a moment :/