# Python: how to send a POST http-request with invalid json inside?

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest, urllib

For API autotests I need to send with Python a http-request with **invalid JSON** in the body.

It should be that:

```
curl -i 'http://[my IP]:3003/signup'   \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"email":"user2@user2.com","password":"testpasswd}}}'

=>
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

{"message":"Unexpected end of JSON input"}
```

But in standard *requests* library it is prohibited

With *requests* I can't send it usual POST-way, because `json.dumps` function and `requests.post(...json=... )` param [never produces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684718/test-using-an-invalid-json-passed-in-test-request-context-flask%5D%20an%20invalid%20JSON%20document) an invalid json

```
def POST(self):
    payload = {"email":"user2@user2.com","password":"testpasswd}}}
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    resp = requests.post(url='http://[my IP]:3003/signup', headers=headers, json=payload
    self.headers = {}
    return resp
```

Based on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684718/test-using-an-invalid-json-passed-in-test-request-context-flask), I even tried to pass invalid json in not-intended-for-that `data` parameter, but got completely another error text in body, than with `curl`

```
INVALID_JSON = """{"email":"user2@user2.com","password":"testpasswd}}"""
def test_signup_with_invalid_json():
    url = BASE_URL + '/signup'
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    payload = INVALID_JSON
    resp = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    print(resp, resp.text)

=> <Response [400]> {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Validation failed","validation":{"body":{"source":"body","keys":["email"],"message":"\"email\" is required"}}}
```

I scanned *requests* documentation and *urllib.request* documentation, but didn't find what I need.  And I couldn't make *http.client* work the way I need

Please help

Comment: You **cannot** use the `json` parameter to `requests.post` because that expects a Python data structure and converts it into valid JSON. You use the `data` parameter to send arbitrary data (in other words it is **exactly** intended for that purpose). However, the data you're sending in your second example isn't JSON at all, because it's using single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`). That is, it doesn't match your `curl` example.

Comment: Thank you for correction, I edited my example code, so that there was a broken-json-like content with params in double quotes
`INVALID_JSON = """{"email":"user2@user2.com","password":"testpasswd}}"""`


It was stated in my question, that I cannot user `requests.post(...json())`, as it works only with valid json. The question was what I *can* use?

When I try to use **data** parameter as in my last example,I get completely another error in http-response body, when with curl, so that isn't the same request.

Comment: Your code example with using the `data` parameter does not pass the `headers` to the `requests.post`. Could it be that the server is trying to parse your broken JSON as something like form-data, and throwing an error based on that?

Comment: Btw, if you have a `curl` command that does what you want, and you'd like to get an equivalent code snippet in your language, consider using a converter like https://sqqihao.github.io/trillworks.html. I often use this when debugging web apps, where I'd copy a request from the browser DevTools, convert it into my language, then use that to automate it.

Comment: Ooooooh, such a stupid mistake. That's my fault. Yes, I checked: when you pass a header `"Content-Type": "application/json"` to requests.post, it works exactly like curl. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes @Danya02 https://sqqihao.github.io/trillworks.html is also very useful, thanks again!